# Can't host a winsock server

Tags: sockets, networking

I am using simple msdn TCP sockets example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When my friends run the server, or when I am using it through my local network everything is fine. But there is no way to connect to server running on my computer through the internet. I opened the port binded by server in my router, disabled Windows firewall, turned off antivirus, but it doesn't work!

Here is what I got in Wireshark, but I don't know what it means:

[image]

192.168.1.2 is my local IP, 17000 is the port, binded by server. I am running both server and client on the same computer here.

Comment: You do not have a global IP address, you'll need to buy one to be able to do that. I suggest you do some more reading on networking, subnets, and NATs.

Comment: You don't need to buy a static IP.  The friend can connect to whatever IP you are currently connected to the Internet with.  If you have a dynamic IP, simply look up your current IP with ipconfig or whatever and give it to the friend to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Run the server on your machine and have it `bind()` to IP `192.168.1.2` (or to `INADDR_ANY` aka `0.0.0.0` to bind to all of the machine's available IPs) on port `17000`, and configure your router to forward all inbound traffic on port `17000` to IP `192.168.1.2`.  Your friends can then connect to your router's public IP on port `17000`.  If your router does not have a static IP assigned by your ISP, you will have to look up the current IP using an external service, such as http://www.whatismyip.com.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I am doing. It works for my friends, but when I host the server it always fails.

Comment: Then either your server is not actually listening (use netstat to verify), your router is not configured correctly, or your ISP is blocking the port on their end. If you are sure of the first two, then the last one is he likely culprit. Some ISPs prevent their customers from running their own servers unless you pay extra for it. Call your ISP and ask about your particular setup.